# How to get complete video url from inspecting the components code on instagram

Tags: html, components, developer-tools, code-inspection

[image]

I'm trying to get the video URL from the Instagram site from the components section. here I can get the source link but it is not complete. you can see in the image at the end of the link some part of the link is wrapped inside three dots. how to get full src of video URL.
It is clickable but with an incomplete URL. So is there any better way to get the link?
The inspecting elements link is wrapped in the div, but I can't get the source there either.

Comment: did you try right-click and copy value of attribute?

Comment: Yes, right-click doesn't give any options.

Answer (score 3):

If i try it in Chrome, i get the full video URL. But you could also use the console in the developer tools, type the following code and press Enter (the selector `#video-id` is just an example):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#video-id').src);
```